# Configure VM Role on Azure Emulator

Tags: azure-vm-role

How can we configure VM Role on Azure Emulator? Is this possible or do i need to do my testing on Windows Azure Management Portal.

Thanks,
Mrinal Jaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Azure F&Q its written that Emulator supports VM role but to much dismay it doesn't. I talked to Microsoft Tech team and got this answer.

One good thing they told me was, if i want to use VM on Azure it will be better if i use extra-small deployment it will increase my compute hours and i can host 2 extra-small VM role on azure in free trail account.